# Check if "zoom_changed" is fired by mouse/google tool?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to know if the zoom is changed because user change it from mouse/google zoom tool (top left of the map, the zoomControl) or just if change after some functions of google (like directionsDisplay.setDirections, or bounds) :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    if (CONDITION) {

    }
});
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect if the zoom has changed based on an action your program has taken by setting a global flag when it performs an action that changes the zoom, clear it when that action is complete (either in the zoom_changed event handler or the idle event handler).

If your flag isn't set, the zoom was caused by a user action.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to listen for the `idle` event, which is a "catch all" event, fired after the user pans or zooms (and it's fired only once). There is also a `zoom_changed` event, fired when the zoom level changes. See all Map events [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

I'm not aware of a way to "know" if the zooming is from user intervention or from a Google Maps API function, without at least [building a custom zoom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomEvents).